# Should I sell items as stacks or smaller amounts?

Tags: moonlighter

When stocking my shop, I can obviously sell a whole stack of artefacts, or just singles.

So far I've been using singles to try and find the 'happy price' to sell items at.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of selling items in larger quantities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It depends on the rarity of the item

Moonlighter prices are influenced by supply and demand (Actually, just by the supply as far as I know),
if you sell a lot of items of the same kind, their individual price will decrease.

#### Common Items

It is fine to sell stacks of low priced common items, because the price drop caused by the increased supply for them is acceptable

#### Rare Items

High-priced items on the other hand should only be sold individually and possibly not too many of the same kind each day, because their value can decrease significantly.

#### The key point is variety

The general rule for keeping the prices nice and profitable is to always have a variety of items rather than a lot of items of the same kind.
This applies to both stacks of inexpensive items and individual expensive artifacts.

Comment: I don't believe selling lots of the same items will cause the popularity to decrease. After finished the game, only once did I have an item decrease in popularity. This was caused by selling the item slightly higher than "perfect price". (where you see a sad face but they still buy it). I can assure you I sold *a lot* of the same items at perfect price with no effect on popularity. I even went through a phase of selling only on type of item in single stacks (to get a trophy) and that didn't effect popularity either.